# How to "print result" that is 'off form' spring boot + jsp + hibernate

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jsp, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm currently fetching data from local sql database and printing results to a local page(jsp).

I've succeeded in 'CRUD'ing data that matches the form that is already made, but having a problem with printing results like 'count' or 'avg'. The only thing I've found is that I can add additionally queries below 'repository', but can't fetch that result.

Here are my codes.

SelectTest.jsp

```
<table width="500" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td width="100">sno</td>
        <td width="100">pno</td>
        <td width="100">name</td>
        <td width="100">year</td>
        <td width="100">dept</td>
    </tr>
    <c:forEach items="${students}" var="student">
        <tr>
            <td width="100">${student.getSno()}</td>
            <td width="100">${student.getPno()}</td>
            <td width="100">${student.getSname()}</td>
            <td width="100">${student.getYear()}</td>
            <td width="100">${student.getDept()}</td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

StudentEntity

```
public class StudentEntity {
    @Id
    @Column(name="SNO")
    private Integer sno;

    @Column(name="PNO")
    private Integer pno;

    @Column(name="SNAME")
    private String sname;

    @Column(name="YEAR")
    private Integer year;

    @Column(name="DEPT")
    private String dept;
}
```

StudentRepository

```
    @Query(
            value = "SELECT * FROM STUDENT",
            nativeQuery = true
    )
    List<StudentEntity> findAll();
    
    @Modifying
    @Transactional
    @Query(
            value  = "INSERT INTO STUDENT(SNO, PNO, SNAME, YEAR, DEPT) " +
                    "VALUES (:sno, :pno, :sname, :year, :dept)",
            nativeQuery = true
    )
    void saveOne(
            @Param("sno") Integer sno,
            @Param("pno") Integer pno,
            @Param("sname") String sname,
            @Param("year") Integer year,
            @Param("dept") String dept
    );

StudentService
    public List<StudentEntity> findAll() {
        return studentRepository.findAll();
    }

    public StudentEntity save(StudentEntity studentEntity){
        studentRepository.saveOne(
                studentEntity.getSno(),
                studentEntity.getPno(),
                studentEntity.getSname(),
                studentEntity.getYear(),
                studentEntity.getDept()
        );
        return studentEntity;
```

DatabaseController

```
@GetMapping(value = "/student")
public ModelAndView stu() {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("selectTest");

    List<StudentEntity> students = studentService.findAll();

    modelAndView.addObject("students", students);

    return modelAndView;
}
```

Comment: What is the exact code that did not work?

Comment: I added query below studentRepository/void saveOne INSERT INTO STUDENT(COUNT(SNO)  VALUES(:countTuple), but oviously didn't work. I can't even tell where to add the codes

Comment: This does not look like a valid SQL query. What are you trying to achieve exactly? When you insert values, you need to specify which columns you want to provide values for. And you cannot insert aggregates like COUNT, only single values.

Comment: To illustrate, your query would try to insert into the STUDENT table a value equal to the count of all rows in that table. Semantically it does not make sense for me.

Comment: Yes, thats the problem. I want to 'count' sno, pno anything that can represent the tuples and print it. The problem is that there are no column/param that can print the result. And I don't think I can write the method as well.

Comment: I also tried @query (value = "SELECT SNO, COUNT(SNO) FROM STUDENT", nativequery = true) List<StudentEntity> countTuple() but the 'List' isn't the correct way to achieve the needed as far as I've searched

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to retrieve data, not insert it. Thus you need a SELECT query. Probably something like `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM STUDENT` for a starter, or you could group records into grouped counts with `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM STUDENT GROUP BY SNO`. You cannot map those results to a Student object though, you have to use a single numeric value (or an array in the second case). I would recommend going through an SQL tutorial first. Then it would be easier to understand what is going under the hood in JPA.

Comment: In general, your query is first executed, then the resulting data is copied to your objects by JPA. However, the returned data must match the structure of the objects exactly. So you make sure that every query returns the exact structure it is meant for.

Comment: What is the error? what is off form? you cannot print count or avg because there is not a single line with that in your code

Comment: the 'off form' was meaning that I don't have a 'td' that can show the asked query results in jsp file. So I think I can just make another 'div' to print the results?